# Programmatically Populate a short text type response on a Google form embedded in a Google site webpage from App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, auto-populate

User enters information on Form A. On form A submission, an on submit trigger runs a sheet side appscript function to look up information (no issues there) and then runs a function to populate a short text type response on Form B. Form A and Form B are hosted on the same Google sites page. Form B does not populate

I have read and experimented with everything I can find on this site. I can get the code to run but I can’t get data to actually populate in form B.

I even tried to build an HMTL form using webapp but ran into same problem I can’t programmatically change response text on the Google sites page.

I’ve tried to reference form B through:

1. getting the URL from the sheet linked to form B
2. using the form Id  from either the edit or view source URL
3. Getting form B prefill link and replacing items

I tried to adapt the following answers located at:
Answer by Mogsdad

- [Apps Script - Programmatically submit answers from Google Sheet to Google Form - ERROR - "Sorry, this response has already been submitted."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813080/apps-script-programmatically-submit-answers-from-google-sheet-to-google-form)
- [how to create a google form response with app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831901/how-to-create-a-google-form-response-with-app-script)
- https://spreadsheet.dev/submit-responses-to-google-form-apps-script

```
      //Function run by onsubmit trigger
      //form B prefill code

      function prefill(){
  
      //get url using form B sheet  
      var sheet_ID ='sheet B ID'; 
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_ID);
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
      var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();  
      console.log(formUrl)
  
      // open form B- get form items - create response array
      var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
      var items = form.getItems();
      var formResponse = form.createResponse();

      // Prefill a short text response
      var formItem = items[0].asTextItem();

      var response = formItem.createResponse("my data");
      formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
  
      // submit response ( also tried urlfetch post method)
      formResponse.submit();
      // nothing fills on Form B
     };
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your script is working OK for me. Just to clarify... FormA responses are linked to S/SheetA. FormB (which contains some questions) responses are linked to S/SheetB. S/SheetA has a project containing function `prefill()`, triggered by Installable `onFormSubmit`, which creates form submission in FormB. When response is manually submitted to FormA, `prefill` is triggered and creates response in FormB. The automated submission to FormB is automatically recorded in S/SheetB. `prefill` requires only one edit: `var sheet_ID ='sheet B ID'`, i.e. ID of S/SheetB.

Comment: Interesting but predictable trivia... Timestamp in S/SheetA is my local time (02/02/2023 08:49:38) since submission was made locally. Timestamp in S/SheetB is GMT (01/02/2023 21:49:40) since submission was made at server??